# How to get all value from table row and column to array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to get all value from table row and column to array

```
field1         field2           field3
  1             aaa              aaa
  2             bbb              bbb
  3             ccc              ccc
  4             ddd              ddd
```

i want to get value from table row to array like below:

```
array1=[["1","aaa","aaa"],["2","bbb","bbb"],["3","ccc","ccc"],["4","ddd","ddd"]];
```

My html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>field1</th>
            <th>field2</th>
            <th>field3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>ccc</td>
            <td>ccc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>ddd</td>
            <td>ddd</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Any solution for this? Thank you

Comment: provide the html

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AshayMandwarya please check my update question

Comment: @jom can you provide me answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your can try:

```js
function get(){
  var table = $('table');
  var data = [];

  table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
    // no thead
    if( i != 0){
      var $tds = $(this).find('td');
      var row = [];
      $tds.each(function (i, el){
        row.push($(this).text());
      });
      data.push(row);
    }
        
  });
  return data;
}


console.log(get());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>field1</th>
            <th>field2</th>
            <th>field3</th>
            <th>field4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>ccc</td>
            <td>ccc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>ddd</td>
            <td>ddd</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if the column count changes (added or removed)?

Comment: @MinhNguyen : thank you very much it's work very well

Comment: i update code with @jom comment (when the column count changes)

Comment: @MinhNguyen if i want to cut two row bottom how can?

Comment: You can user Array `slice()` method to get 2 row bottom after get all data. Example `get().slice(-2)`